# How to destroy the previous activity in android?

Tags: android

I am currently stuck in the situation where I am currently in activity B which was called from activity A. So what I want is when a certain condition occurs in activity B then activity A is removed from the stack so that it will not be present when the user presses the back button. Removing all the activities is not an option because there are other activities before A which I don't want to destroy.I specifically need to destroy only activity A.

Comment: You can finish activity on the callback "onActivityResult" of activity A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply finish the activity A when you are starting activity B.

Something like:

```
startActivty(intent);
this.finish();
```

`this` refers to current Activity (Activity A) and `intent` has the intent to open Activity B.

Edit: For removing the Activity A in certain condition only:

```
startActivityForResult(intent); // Starting Activity B.
```

Then in Activity B:

```
onBackPressed() {
    setResult(...); // Set result as RESULT_OK etc based on condition. You can also send some data.
}
```

Then again in Activity A:

```
onActivityResult(...) {
    if ( ... ) // check the condition value from the result
        finish();
}
```

Comment: i only need to delete the activity A when certain condition is fulflled in activity B. else the activity A need to be in the stack.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see that in question. You can simply intercept back press (onBackPressed) and then kill the previous activity too. 

Start the Activity B as `startActivityForResult` and then onBackPress, send the data back to Activity A which can be intercepted in `onActivityResult` - there you can simply finish() the activity A if needed.

Comment: @Ibrahim No it will just clear the Activity A, as finish() is called for that only.

Answer (score 0):

You can add flag with intent also, if you don't want to keep your activity in back-stack ,

```
    Intent intent= new Intent(...);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Activity A

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public static Activity a;
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        a=this;
    } 
 ......
 }
```

In Activity B

```
    public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

      //Finish Activity here, like on button click
     btn= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.close);
     btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      
     @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
      MainActivity.a.finish();           //To finish MainActivity
    }
 });


  } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When You Start Activity B From Activity A Just use finish()

`Intent intent=new Intent(A.this,B.class);
startActivty(intent);
this.finish();`